# Can the XP 'Computer Locked' dialog box be customized?

Tags: windows-xp

I'd like to customize the 'computer locked' dialog box in XP to be more graphic oriented, is there any way to do this, or perhaps just change the colors of the box?

Also, I'm running dual monitors and would like the box to be positioned in the center of the two screens rather than in the center of Monitor 1 (main).  Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with a custom msgina.dll it should be possible. Have a look at [this](http://www.troublefixers.com/how-to-hide-computer-locked-window-in-windows-xp/) article about hiding the computer locked dialog which has a replacement msgina.dll.

A warning though before experimenting: msgina.dll is a core system dll which handles the logon process. If you replace it with something that doesn't work you might end up with a computer that is impossible to log on to.

Comment: +1 This would work. Also, if you have a fubar gina.dll you can still get into Safe Mode and change the registry or replace the file.

Answer (score 1):

Its not very difficult:

I know that WindowBlinds can do this but this was so long ago so I forgot how to do it.

[Stardock windowblinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/)

There is also tuneUp utilities that can do it in a more conservative way.

[TuneUp](http://www.tune-up.com/products/tuneup-utilities/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Not easily
2. You can change your monitors to horizontal span mode in the video card settings.
   Details depend on your video card.